# Are specific model/service provider questions appropriate?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

e.g. I want to ask a question if anyone has more details or has seen any update on when Sprint will be rolling out 4G to New York.

This is because I have an EVO 4G, which is an android phone.  But the question itself is only indirectly related to android.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would certainly hope that model-specific questions are appropriate, otherwise we've rendered the entire site impotent as a support resource.

However, your *specific* example question seems both speculative and not specific to Android, which probably *isn't* going to be considered on topic here.

Comment: I'd have to agree. Questions about the Evo (or any other model) - fine.Questions about Sprint (or any other provider, anywhere) - not so much

Answer (score 1):

Specific model/service provider questions are good -- but specific model compared to specific model questions are bad for multiple reasons

- subjective (usually, unless specs only)
- the market changes so fast -- comparing these two apples is pointless in another two months, I would think.